# Is the place of the word "alike" correct?

Tags: conjunctions, word-order

> Many facilities for young and old are offered alike by the resort.

In the sentence, is the place of the word "alike" correct?

Comment: I find *no* problem in that!

Comment: It's correct in my view too. But this is just a wild guess: ***Many facilities for young and old alike are offered by the resort.*** It can mean a different thing, too, probably.

Comment: I would say that's strange usage. The previously mentioned "**Many facilities for young and old alike are offered by the resort.**" sounds better.

Comment: "Many facilities are offered by the reset are offered for young and old alike", takes out some of the ambiguities.  Assuming there is one set of facilities that are shared by young and old.As the sentence stands, it sounds like there are two separate sets of facilities, one for young, one for old, however they are very similar in what they offer for each group.

Comment: I'd like to rewrite your sentence as "Many facilities are offered by the resort for young and old alike."

Answer (score 2):

> Many facilities for young and old are offered alike by the resort.

There's nothing wrong with the sentence as commented by Maulik; the word "alike" has been used as an adverb which modifies the verb "offer."

> Many facilities for young and old alike are offered by the resort.

This sentence is also OK; the adverb "alike" modifies "young and old in the sentence."

However, I think the sentence presented by Yethu as follows sounds more idiomatic and easy on the ear:

> Many facilities are offered by the resort for young and old alike.

Answer (score 0):

> Many facilities are offered by the resort for young and old alike.

In the sentence, the phrase "for young and old alike" has been used as an adjective phrase that modifies "the resort".